# WPF Changing inner view of window and creating a list of objects

Tags: wpf

So I'm trying to make a simple messaging application. I already have my database, my classes, and everything set up. Now I need to figure out how to do the layout.

I want buttons to the left, Inbox, Sent Messages, Deleted Messages, etc. Now obviously I don't want to create a new window every time a button is pressed. So how do I keep the buttons etc, but change the content of the screen (similar to android activity/fragment)?

Ans is it possible to create a list of all the messages (containing subject, part of the content, etc) dynamically and add a click function to each one of them? Similar to recyclerview?

I'm quite new to WPF so I don't really know how to do much.

Comment: Do you want us to do your Layout based on a very vague description?

Comment: I just want an idea of which layout elements I should use to create something like this, I don't want my layout to be done. Sorry

Comment: You should start with usercontrols, customcontrols and ContentControl

Comment: You should start with a book.  One geared towards MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon a **TabControl** could turn out very well for the kind of layout you want, this is an example of how to use it:

**XAML File**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabItem Header="Inbox" Height="30">
            <TabItem.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </TabItem.LayoutTransform>
            <TabItem.Content>
                Content of Inbox Window
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Sent Items">
            <TabItem.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </TabItem.LayoutTransform>
            <TabItem.Content>
                Content of Sent Items Window
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Deleted Items">
            <TabItem.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </TabItem.LayoutTransform>
            <TabItem.Content>
               Content of - guess what - deleted items
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

that will look like that:
[image]